# Exact description of parent inheritance

Tags: maven, maven-3

Both the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) and [Nexus Book](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-relationships.html#ex-inheritance) have only a superficial description.

There are some details on merging plugin configuration, but that's all.

I just noticed a weird behavior: namely adding a `<resources>/<resource>` element seems to *override* parent declarations rather than doing an append or merge.

Can I find a more detailed description of the merge algorithm somewhere on the Web, or is reading the source code the only way to find out?

If it's just code can somebody point where to look, or should I just check what `effective-pom` mojo calls?

Comment: If you mentione resources which does not make sense to merge this definition...cause Maven follows convention over configuration paradigm which makes it useless to use an inheritance in this case...

Comment: @khmarbaise what you are saying is true when inheriting from Maven's global super-pom. However in case where I have one project-wide pom with deafault layout and would like to add extra folder in one of submodules merging instead of overriding would be useful.

Comment: @khmarbaise still a complete description of how the inheritance works would be useful regardless of weather one agrees with the design choices there or not